# How to fix Malformed URL Exception in Java?

Tags: java, url

I'm writing a program that fetches information from websites online, and the function that gets the content is not working when it was on other projects. I used debug mode and I believe the problem is coming from the line that declares the URL object. The documentation says that a Malformed URL Exception should only happen if the protocol is wrong or the String is null

```
try {
    System.out.println("URL is "+ trainServiceURL); 
    url = new URL(trainServiceURL); //gets webpage
```

The print line outputs:

```
URL is http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/search/advancedhandler?type=advanced&location=2A01&toc=All&earlier_cp=&later_cp=&timespan=now&show=all&order=wtt&stp_wtt=1&stp_var=1&stp_stp=1&stp_can=0
```

This works in google chrome, and has the correct protocol. I have catch statements for Malformed URL Exception and IO Exception at the end of the try statement, but neither of them appear to have triggered (they are meant to print a stack trace). What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have a catch block for a MalformedURLException and it's not triggering?  What makes you think you are getting one?  Is there some console output or something?  Can you expand your code sample a bit?  Are you sure it's not getting to the next line?

Comment: Catch `Exception`, print the stack trace. Copy and paste that stacktrace. If possible share some more of your code.

Comment: _'This works in google chrome'_ The page you are refering to uses **https** but you have http. Change it and try again. I can succesfully print the content.

Comment: Thank you very much Eritrean, I assumed it was http as the link worked in chrome, but it must be programmed to change it. I tried https and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a problem with your code, at least not with what you have given us.

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/search/advancedhandler?type=advanced&location=2A01&toc=All&earlier_cp=&later_cp=&timespan=now&show=all&order=wtt&stp_wtt=1&stp_var=1&stp_stp=1&stp_can=0");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```